# how to stop nouiSlider from sliding lower than a certain value?

Tags: jquery, nouislider

how to stop the nouiSlider lower than a certain value.

I think it could be something at

```
slider.nouiSlider.on('change', function(){
});
```

this is what I already done.

```
 var slider = document.getElementById('year-slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [1],
    step: 1,
    connect: 'lower',
    behaviour: 'snap',
    range: {
        'min':0,
        'max':8
    }
});


var lSlide = document.getElementById('year-slider');
var lChange = document.getElementById('year-slider');

highlightLabel(INDEX);
function addClassFor ( element, className, duration ) {
    element.classList.add(className);
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.classList.remove(className);
    }, duration);
}

slider.noUiSlider.on('change', function(){
    addClassFor(lChange, 'tShow', 450);
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('slide', function(){
    addClassFor(lSlide, 'tShow', 450);
});
```

not sure how exactly to do that.

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how can you set a min and a max value for the slider?

Comment: @LuigiCerone I am sorry, I just edited my question showing what I have already done.

What I want to do is, I do not want the to go below say 15000 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `slider.noUiSlider.set()` on the `change` event:

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('change', function ( values, handle ) {
    if ( values[handle] < 15000 ) {
        softSlider.noUiSlider.set(15000);
    }
});
```

See [this example](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/) in the documentation to try it out.